# "Undefined offset" при выборе результатов preg_match

Tags: php

Код:

```
$news = array();
foreach ($parse as $index => $value) {
    preg_match($value, $main_page, $matches);
    $news[$index] = $matches;
}
var_dump($news);
```

Получаю вот такой массив:

```
'name' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '<h1 class="moviename-big" itemprop="name">Гладиатор</h1>' (length=65)
      1 => string 'Гладиатор' (length=18)
'originalname' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '<span itemprop="alternativeHeadline">Gladiator</span>' (length=53)
      1 => string 'Gladiator' (length=9)
'year' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'год</td>
                <td><div style="position: relative">
                    <a href="/lists/m_act%5Byear%5D/2000/" title="">2000</a>' (length=141)
      1 => string '2000' (length=4)
'country_title' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'страна</td>
                <td><div style="position: relative">
                    <a href="/lists/m_act%5Bcountry%5D/1/">США</a>, <a href="/lists/m_act%5Bcountry%5D/11/">Великобритания</a>
                </div></td>' (length=242)
      1 => string '<div style="position: relative">
                    <a href="/lists/m_act%5Bcountry%5D/1/">США</a>, <a href="/lists/m_act%5Bcountry%5D/11/">Великобритания</a>
                </div>' (length=199)
'slogan' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'слоган</td><td style="color: #555">&laquo;Генерал, ставший рабом. Раб, ставший гладиатором. Гладиатор, бросивший вызов империи&raquo;</td></tr>' (length=219)
      1 => string '&laquo;Генерал, ставший рабом. Раб, ставший гладиатором. Гладиатор, бросивший вызов империи&raquo;' (length=168)
```

Если пишу так:

```
$news = array();
foreach ($parse as $index => $value) {
    preg_match($value, $main_page, $matches);
    $news[$index] = $matches[1];
}
var_dump($news);
```

То получаю `Undefined offset: 1`. Почему и как исправить?

Comment: Проверьте сначала наличие индекса: `if (isset($matches[1])) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В одной из итераций не находит группу с индексом 1 из $value в $main_page. Соответственно в matches[1] ничего не попадет, а будет только в $matches[0] все выражение, если было совпадение. Выше верно написали, проверяйте сущестование $matches[1] перед записью. Ну или из категории вредные советы - костыль с @.

UPD для примера

```
  $value = '/(\w+): (\d+)?/';
  $main_page = 'News: 2016';
  preg_match($value, $main_page, $matches);
  var_dump ($matches);
```

Вывод:

```
array (size=3)
0 => string 'News: 2016' (length=10)
1 => string 'News' (length=4)
2 => string '2016' (length=4)

$value = '/(\w+): (\d+)?/';
$main_page = 'News: zzz';
preg_match($value, $main_page, $matches);
var_dump ($matches);
```

Вывод

```
array (size=2)
0 => string 'News: ' (length=6)
1 => string 'News' (length=4)
```

Во втором варианте нет совпадений c секцией (\d+), соответственно, matches[2] не существует. Так же и у Вас в каком то случае нет совпадений между value и main_page. В массиве с результатами нет элемента с индексом 1.

Comment: честно вообще не понял о чем вы можете попробовать в коде изобразить.

Comment: @Sergalas а представленный вами `var_dump` массива полный, или это часть из него? Потому что в нём не видно ни одного подмассива из 1 элемента, что идёт вразрез с идеей ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, проверив, были ли вообще совпадения:

```
if (preg_match($value, $main_page, $matches)) {
    $news[$index] = $matches[1];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

> preg_match() возвращает 1, если параметр pattern соответствует
>   переданному параметру subject, 0 если нет, или FALSE в случае ошибки.